# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio starts to consume 100% of CPU after a while when the VPN connection to the SQL Server is disconnected

Tags: ssms, sql-management-studio

Closed. This question does not meet Stack Overflow guidelines. It is not currently accepting answers.

This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Closed 11 hours ago.

This is bugging me for years now and no solution (I'm guessing it's a Microsoft problem).

I connect to many different VPNs and then to either a test or production Microsoft SQL Server through the VPN.

When I have SSMS opened and connected to the server via VPN on my develop computer and I disconnect the VPN or it loses connection, after a while (can't say exactly how long, but usually after a few hours), the SSMS app on the dev computer starts to consume all available CPU on all cores (jumps to 100%).

The version of SQL Server seems to be irrelevant (happens on 2008 R2, 2012, 2016 and 2022).

Usually it happens when Microsoft VPN is used. Either OOTB Microsoft VPN or with a plugin like FortiClient VPN.

Happens on SSMS version 17, 18 and 19 (maybe even earlier versions, don't know cause I didn't use them much).

My dev machine was a Windows 7 with this issue, but migrated to Windows 11 and the problem still remains.

To me it seems more like a SSMS problem, that Microsoft isn't able to fix.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you contacted Microsoft for support?

Comment: Any plugins installed in SSMS?  What else do you have open in SSMS when it happens, Object Explorer, queries, etc?

Comment: Happens on stock SSMS, no plugins. Have not contacted Microsoft support because they are usually very unresponsive.

Usually there is a connection to the server in "Object Explorer" and there are Queries that are connected to the server, but not running.